# App-like Light/Brightening effect

Tags: css

does anybody know if there's a way to create an `CSS` effect which looks like the light effect used for `iPhone apps`? I mean the upper, brighter part of the box.

Thanks,

Ron

[image]

Comment: here is what google says http://www.xorph.com/nfd/2010/06/10/iphone-icon-gloss-overlay-in-pure-css/ but what have you tried first?

Comment: I googled alot but couldn't find a final proof that this will work in css... thanks to @Stecman i have a solution that seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately since using `:after` and `:before` selectors on `img` elements is [not covered by the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/CR-CSS2-20090908/generate.html#before-after-content), a pure CSS solution might not behave correctly:

> This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before
>   and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML). This will be
>   defined in more detail in a future specification.

In the current versions of Chrome and Firefox, these selectors appear to be ignored and simply don't work on `img` elements.

**Here's a solution with a small HTML wrapper** that will fall back to not rendering when the CSS isn't supported. The container size needs to be specified here, but that could easily be set with JavaScript.

**CSS**

```
.shine {
    width:223px;
    height:223px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:inline-block;
}

.shine:after {
    width:150%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:-45%;
    left:-25%;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    border-radius:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="shine">
    <img src="" alt="">
</span>
```

**Result**

To make this a little fancier, you could add a gradient background to `.shine:after`, but it works fine without to demonstrate the idea.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTvMf/1/) so you don't have to take my word for it.

[image: CSS shine effect]

Comment: really a great solution. but for some reason it just works for images with dark backgrounds... any idea how to adjust it, that it works for any image?

Comment: @Ron have a fiddle with the line `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);`. I used [RGBA notation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/RGBA), but since the overlay is its own element you could use also use the `opacity` property and any background configuration. As it is, the overlay is a very transparent white so it won't show up well on lighter colours. You might be able to remedy this by increasing the opacity, though keep in mind that CSS opacity is additive and the colour channels can't go beyond their full values of 255 (ie. this overlay won't show up at all on 100% white).

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen the effect you describe (would never use an iPhone) but I assume it is somehow animated? 
Then you can do that in css if you use two images and blend them 'on hover'. You position the 'light icon' above the plain icon (typically using an `:after` pseudo selector in css) and control it's opacity value using a css `:hover` selector).